# What are the extreme points of the 2-2-2 no-signaling polytope?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I've been told that the set of no-signaling correlations is a polytope.

How do I find the extreme points of 2-2-2 no-signaling correlations? Here "2-2-2" refers to the two-parties scenarios in which each party has two inputs to choose from, and can observe one of two possible outcomes.

Comment: I think it would help if you would add details (such as this) to the question.

Comment: I suppose you are asking for explicit expressions? If you only want a method to get the vertices, the problem is essentially that of finding the intersection between a bunch of hyperplanes (the various constraints) and the positive sector (set of $p$ with $p_i\ge0$). This can be solved using e.g. linear programming.

Comment: @glS I'd bet in this case the extremal points are deterministic.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22064/55

Answer (score 1):

The vertices (extreme points) of the 2-2-2 no-signalling polytope can be found in [this paper (Barrett et al., 2005)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.022101). There are 24 of them, 16 of which are (Bell-)local:
$$ p(ab|xy) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } a = \alpha x \oplus \beta \text{ and } b = \gamma y\oplus \delta, \\ 0 &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}, $$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ range over $\{0,1\}$. These are exactly the deterministic local correlations, the convex hull of which is the polytope of local correlations.

The other 8 vertices of the 2-2-2 no-signalling polytope are nonlocal:
$$ p(ab|xy) = \begin{cases} 1/2 &\text{ if } a\oplus b = xy \oplus \alpha x \oplus \beta y \oplus \gamma, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}, $$
where, again, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ range over $\{0,1\}$.

Note that only the 16 local vertices are deterministic.